# sql syntax error in a subquery selection for a random choice

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select op.id, op.nome,op.cognome,
   (select tp.inizio
    from turni_preconf as tp
    where tp.tot_ore = op.ore_giornaliere
    order by rand()
    limit 1
  ) as randomin,
addtime(randomin,op.ore_giornaliere_time) as rnout

from operatori as op
```

the error are : Unknown column 'randomin' in 'field list' i have a little doubt for the sub query ex select in but i have tryed and don't work

Comment: You're trying to perform a function on a column that does not exist. The error indicates that you're trying to use the alias of the sub-select - 'randomin'

Comment: in this case I believe the error is that the scope of randomin is unknown to the function addtime at run time.  However, if you were to instead move the calculation to a join in the from clause, it would be available at run time.

Comment: ok thnks..how fix it??

Comment: possible answer listed below.  I'm not sure if it will work though it's untested.  An alternate method would be to write it as a function passing in the Op.ore_Giornaliere and call out to it in both cases.  bit slow; but i'm pretty sure that would work.  I think the join would be faster, but I'm not sure I have the syntax right

Comment: move the subquery to the from clause... answer coming shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the subquery to the FROM clause...

```
select op.id, op.nome,op.cognome,
  r.val as randomin,
  addtime(r.val, op.ore_giornaliere_time) as rnout
from operatori as op,
(select tp.inizio as val
 from turni_preconf as tp, operatori as op2
 where tp.tot_ore = op2.ore_giornaliere
 order by rand()
 limit 1
) as r
```

Comment: I forget if operatori needs to be specified again in the inner query, its possible that this could be cleaned up. But this should definitely WORK.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use field aliases in the same "level" of the query, e.g.

```
select somefield AS foo, otherfield = foo AS bar
                 ^^^^^^--create alias
                                      ^^^^--use alias, not ok
```

Answer (score 0):

UNTESTED:
Updated join was wrong I didn't have the right criteria.

Perhaps...

```
select op.id, op.nome,op.cognome, addtime(randomin,op.ore_giornaliere_time) as rnout,
b.randomin
from operatori as op
INNER JOIN 
   (select tot_ore, tp.inizio as randomin
    from turni_preconf as tp
    order by rand()
    limit 1
  ) b on b.tot_ore = op.ore_giornaliere
```

Comment: i can't use a join because i can't a limit random.. please help me

Comment: if you can create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data I can look at it.